# Can't post value to next HTML-document with hidden input

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to post a value to another HTML-document by a hidden input. Then I want to recieve the value with location.search and do something in the new HTML-document. The problem is that the doucment is opening, but the value isn't sent. Here is the HTML:

```
<form action="britzcwka.html" method="post" id="formID">
 <input id="inpt" type="hidden" name="myInput" value="">
</form>
```

And here is the JavaScript-code:

```
document.getElementById("inpt").value = someValue;
alert(document.getElementById("inpt").value);
document.getElementById("theForm").submit();
```

The alert shows the correct value, but the address url is just britzcwka.html when on the other page.

Hank

Comment: Your ID is `formID`, but the alert has `"formId"`. And a `form` doesn't have a `.value`. and you show no element with `"theForm"` for an ID. So overall, everything is a mess.

Comment: edited...I didn't copy/past.

Answer (score 2):

You're using POST method, so your variables will not be included in the browser's address bar. Change form's `method` to `GET`:

```
<form method="GET" action="britzcwka.html" id="formID">
    <!-- form's content -->
</form>
```